# What happens when I assign a pointer to another pointer?

Tags: c++

I am facing a problem understanding this code were a pointer points to another pointer. I am required to find the output but I am confused at the line P equals Q, what does that mean? here is the code:

```
int x;
int y;
int *p = &x;
int *q = &y;
x = 35; y = 46;
p = q;
*p = 78;
cout << x << " " << y << endl;
cout << *p << " " << *q << endl;
```

thanks

Comment: There is no line in your code of the form "Q equals P".      Remember assignment is to the left i.e. an expression `p = q` changes the value of `p`, and is described in words as "p equals q" or more correctly as "p is assigned the value of q".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
p = q
```

is setting the value stored at `p` (which is a pointer) to be equal to the value stored in `q` (also a pointer). Pointers store addresses as their value, so that line is making `p` and `q` store the same address now.

So basically you are changing `p` to point at **the address** of the integer `y`.

Continuing from there, the next line:

```
*p = 78;
```

is going to the address stored in `p` and changing the value to be `78`.

Answer (score 1):

Means that both pointers now point to **y** value

```
p = q;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through line by line:
First we are declaring integers `x`, and `y`,

```
int x;
int y;
```

Then we are creating  pointer `*p` and assigning `x`'s address to it by saying,

```
int *p = &x;
```

Then we are creating  pointer `*q` and assigning `y`'s address to it by saying,

```
int *q = &y;
```

You must know that pointers points to addresses, and `&` operator return's operand's address.

Then we are assigning `x = 35; y = 46;`. You need to know that `p` still points to `x` and `q` still points to `y`.

Then in line `p = q;`,
**we are saying that pointer `p` will point address that `q` is pointing to (which is `y`'s address)**

In line `*p = 78` we are dereferencing pointer `p` and assigning 78 to it. What does it mean? Well, remember pointer `p` was pointing `y`, so we are changing `y`'s value to 78 in this case.

Now `x` is 35 and `y` is 78. Also pointers `p` and `q` still pointing to `y`'s address.

Line `cout << x << " " << y << endl` will print `35 78`,

and line `cout << *p << " " << *q << endl` will print `78 78` because remember pointers `p` and `q` was pointing to `y` and dereferencing these pointers will show `y`'s value which is 78.

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused at the line Q equals P, what does that mean?

I am guessing you mean the line "p = q;"

It is trivial to write code to command the compiler to present more information.

The following cout's report both address and value info.

---

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::cerr, std::endl, std::hex, std::dec, std::cin, std::flush; // c++17

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw, std::setfill;

#include <string>
using std::string, std::to_string;

#include <sstream>
using std::stringstream;


int main(int , char** )
{
   int retVal = 0;

   int x;
   int y;

   int *p = &x;  // p points to x
   int *q = &y;  // q points to y

   x = 35; y = 46; // assignment

   // addresses of ---------------------vv----------------vv
   cout << "\n  &x &y: " << setw(16) << &x << setw(16) << &y
   //              ---------------------vv----------------vv--values of
        << "\n   x  y: " << setw(16) <<  x << setw(16) <<  y << endl;

   // addresses of ---------------------vv----------------vv
   cout << "\n  &p &q: " << setw(16) << &p << setw(16) << &q
   //              ---------------------vv----------------vv--values of pointers
        << "\n   p  q: " << setw(16) <<  p << setw(16) <<  q
   //              ---------------------vv----------------vv--values of what pointers point at
        << "\n  *p *q: " << setw(16) << *p << setw(16) << *q << endl;

   cout << "\n  p = q; ... now p and q both point to y";
   p = q;

   cout << "\n  *p = 78 ... now y is 78" << flush;
   *p = 78;
   cout << "\n              and x is unchanged: " << x << endl;

   // addresses of ---------------------vv----------------vv
   cout << "\n  &x &y: " << setw(16) << &x << setw(16) << &y
   //              ---------------------vv----------------vv--values of
        << "\n   x  y: " << setw(16) <<  x << setw(16) <<  y << endl;

   cout << "\n  and both p and q point to y" ;
   // addresses of ---------------------vv----------------vv
   cout << "\n  &p &q: " << setw(16) << &p << setw(16) << &q
   //              ---------------------vv----------------vv--values of pointers
        << "\n   p  q: " << setw(16) <<  p << setw(16) <<  q
   //              ---------------------vv----------------vv--values of what pointers point at
        << "\n  *p *q: " << setw(16) << *p << setw(16) << *q << endl;
   // after assignment, p & q -----------^-----------------^--- point to the same address

   return retVal;
}
```

---

Typical output:

```
  &x &y:   0x7ffeefe1e9bc  0x7ffeefe1e9c0
   x  y:               35              46

  &p &q:   0x7ffeefe1e9c8  0x7ffeefe1e9d0
   p  q:   0x7ffeefe1e9bc  0x7ffeefe1e9c0
  *p *q:               35              46

  p = q; ... now p and q both point to y
  *p = 78 ... now y is 78
              and x is unchanged: 35

  &x &y:   0x7ffeefe1e9bc  0x7ffeefe1e9c0
   x  y:               35              78

  and both p and q point to y
  &p &q:   0x7ffeefe1e9c8  0x7ffeefe1e9d0
   p  q:   0x7ffeefe1e9c0  0x7ffeefe1e9c0
  *p *q:               78              78
```

---

As coded, these addresses are all in automatic vars ... no dynamic memory used.